# Continue from where it was left off?

Tags: java, android, save

If I am adding a number in my app let's say upto 15, I want to make sure the next time I open my app no matter if it crashed, phones was restarted, or app was exited; it should continue from number 15 rather than the 0. How can I work on that?

I tried something like this. This is probably wrong not sure how to fix it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
            i++;
            txt.setText(" " + i);
            i++;
            editor.putInt("Scores: ", i);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });


}

  }
```

Comment: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Please see what I have tried so far.

Comment: Put the `putInt` stuff in the `onPause` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //  let i be previously saved value or default to zero
            i = app_preferences.getInt("Scores: ",0);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

            i++;
            txt.setText(" " + i);

            //i++;  maybe DONT really increment twice (unless thats what you intended)
            editor.putInt("Scores: ", i);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });


}

  }
```

Comment: This works! The only problem now is that when I reopen the app, instead of the "int" it shows nothing until the button is clicked but I want to make the previous number is being shown. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I think I got this now. I have placed txt.setText(" " + i); before onClick() method.